# How can I show midnight as 24 and not 00 in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

Currently I'm trying to create a scheduler and to handle on the cases, I need to check if currentHours < 24

The problem is that midnight shows as 00 and not 24 but I want it to be formatted as 24 for my usecase

Example

```
const now = moment()
const hours = now.hours() // Output is 0 for 05.1.2023 and 0 for 06.1.2023

if(hours < 24) {...}

// What I want is midnight to be formatted as 24 and not 00
```

What I want is to show the startOf a day as 0 but the end of a day as 24 (regardless if it's the start of the next day or not)

I tried comparing with dates which worked but now I reworked my code to use only hours and so that method doesn't work anymore

Thanks

Edit: Actually if there is a way in moment to check if currentTime is part midnight or not that would also save my issue

Comment: Please read this again,"What I want is to show the startOf a day as 0 but the end of a day as 24 (regardless if it's the start of the next day or not)" draw it on a paper or something to get it clear to yourself.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is a way to check if a date-time is on a certain date. I'm afraid every single time is equal to, or past midnight (On whatever day that time belongs to)

Answer (score 1):

**00:00:00** is never the end of the day. If you check it with `now.endOf('day')`, you can see that the last moment of the current day is actually **23:59:59**.

To achieve what you want, you may need to check that time is **00:00:00** and day is **the following day**.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do this

```
const now = moment()
const hours = now.hours() // Output is 0 for 05.1.2023 and 0 for 06.1.2023

if(hours < 24 && hours != 0) {...}
```

Comment: The issue is I want it to only filter for midnight of the current day and not startOf the day